# Memory leak for MFMailcomposeviewcontroller on send mail

Tags: ios5, instruments, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My app used MFMailcomposeviewcontroller for send mail.I used instrument to check leak,when i press send button in mail compose got more leaks in foundation and messageUI framework and [image]attached screen shot of instrument leak.can any one help me to solve it.

Comment: U got the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an absolutely amazing [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial) on debugging memory leaks in Xcode with Instruments. It will teach you to interpret that display for yourself.