# MFMailComposeViewController never deallocates

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm presenting an MFMailComposeViewController like this:

```
mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
 mc = nil;
```

and removing it with the delegate method:

```
- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The problem is that the VC is never deallocated, and opening and closing the "send email" function in my app eats up memory but doesn't release it.

What am I missing? I don't see how I can do this any other way, and all my other VCs deallocate fine on their own after calling the dismissviewcontroller on themselves.

Comment: do you have strong reference to mailComposeDelegate? If so try with making it weak.

Comment: Is `mc` a local variable or an instance variable?

Comment: No strong references. Tried both instance variable and local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you set **mc = nil**; immediately after **presentViewController:mc**?

You should do something like:-

```
mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Then

```
- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller 
            didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    mc=nil;
}];
}
```

By the way, MFMailComposeViewController has memory leak issue. It is not only your problem, we all have the same problem.

1. [Cancelling MFMailComposeViewController causes a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708510/cancelling-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-causes-a-memory-leak)
2. [Memory leak for MFMailcomposeviewcontroller on send mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907372/memory-leak-for-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-on-send-mail)

Comment: 1) This assumes `mc` is an instance variable and not a local variable. 2) Your change makes no difference. There is nothing wrong with setting `mc=nil` right after presenting the controller.

Comment: I tried various combinations of mc=nil, but nothing works. I also tried just never touching it. I tried both local variable and instance variable. No change.

Comment: And good to know it's not just me. It was driving me crazy. I don't know why I didn't find those threads when Googling!!

Comment: @nickdnk yes, I am having the same problem with my app. It adds about 1 mb to the memory each time I present and dismiss the MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: So basically Apple needs to look at this. Hardly anything we can do about it it seems. Too bad. Upvoted for links to other threads.

Comment: Yes, I believe we can not do anything much. I might try to find/make a custom MFMailComposeViewController when I am free. Thanks for the upvote. ;)